# Display Decision Tree in IPython Notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, graphviz, decision-tree

My goal is to display decision trees in an IPython notebook. My problem is that when I try to render it, it opens a new window whilst I would like it to be dislayed inline (like matplotlib plots).

Here is the code I use :

```
def show_tree(decisionTree, out_file, feature_names):
    out_file = 'viz_tree/' + out_file
    export_graphviz(decisionTree, out_file=out_file, feature_names=feature_names)
    dot = ''
    with open(out_file, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            dot += line
    dot = Source(dot)
    return dot

decisionTree.fit(inputs, outputs)
d = show_tree(decisionTree, 'tree.dot', col_names)
d.render(view=True)
```

I know it is possible to do so because of this [example](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz/blob/master/examples/notebook.ipynb).

Do you have any idea how I could do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I ended up doing is installing the [pydot library](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot) from the sources (the pip install seems broken for python3) and then using this function:

```
import io
from scipy import misc

def show_tree(decisionTree, file_path):
    dotfile = io.StringIO()
    export_graphviz(decisionTree, out_file=dotfile)
    pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dotfile.getvalue()).write_png(file_path)
    i = misc.imread(file_path)
    plt.imshow(i)

# To use it
show_tree(decisionT, 'test.png')
```

This keep the image in the file which path is defined by file_path. And then read it simply as a png to display it.

Hope it will help some of you !